# Javascript Updated prices with exp:resso Store

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, jquery

I would like Expresso Store to update my product price every time I choose a modifier. Is there an easy way to do this built into the store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store has built in dynamic price variables you can use. You can see all of the avilable variables [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#dynamic_product_variables). You would want to use

```
<span class="store_product_price"></span>
```

To adjust the price when modifiers are changed.

Comment: I am sure this works in theory, but when I add the class to my span like this: <span class="store_product_price">{price}</span> It doesn't update when I change my modifiers.

Comment: It is hard to track down without knowing EE version, Store version, if you have any JS errors in the console

Comment: EE 2.5.3 is my current version number.

Comment: I would first recommend you take a look at your products in the store_example templates that were installed when you installed Store to see if the price updates dynamically when you change your modifiers.

Comment: Here is the verdict: I have no javascript errors. I have the latest version of the store and of EE. All seems to be working, except...I am unable to get the modifiers to change the price with the dynamic price variable.

Comment: Found the Problem! Expresso Store had a bug that was fixed with the latest update 1.6.2